# I have a few questions on real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

1. How exactly do I get the images and inverse images? My problem is focused on $f(x) = sin(x)$.

a. $f({0, \pi/2, \pi, 3\pi/2, 2\pi})$

b. $f([0, 2\pi])$

c. $f^{-1}({0})$

d. $f^{-1}((0, \infty))$

My results were a. $\{-1,1\}$ b. $[-1, 1]$ c. $\{0, \infty\}$ d. Not attempted, my answer is always marked wrong.

1. Proving if $f,g$ are continuous, then so is the composition of $g o f = g(f)$. 
   a. Using epsilon-delta definition
   b. sequence version of continuity (luckily, I understand this one)
2. Find a compact set with the inverse being not compact.
3. Figure out an image of an open set that does not have to be open
4. Differences between continuity and uniform continuity.

That is all I can't truly figure out along with the professor giving lousy demonstrations on the materials.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be put on hold, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one?).

Answer (score 1):

Well, some of your answers are wrong indeed. Remembering our basic trigonometry, for example

$$\sin x=\sin(x+2k\pi)\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z$$

so (you remember $\;\sin x\;$ is an odd function...?)

$$\sin\frac\pi2=1=-\sin\frac{3\pi}2=\sin\left(-\frac\pi2\right)\;,\;\;\sin k\pi=0\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z$$

and thus the first answer must be $\;\{-1,0,1\}\;$

Your answer (b) is correct, (c) is wrong in at least two levels: writing $\;\{0,\infty\}\;$ measn you're considering $\;\infty\;$ as a real *point*, which it is not.

Also, by the above:

$$\sin^{-1}(\{0\})=\{k\pi\;;\;k\in\Bbb Z\}\;$$

Finally, observe that

$$\sin^{-1}(0,\infty)=\sin^{-1}(0,1]=\left\{\;x\in\Bbb R\;;(2k\pi\le x\le2k+1)\pi]\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\;\right\}=$$

$$=\bigcup_{k\in\Bbb Z}(2k\pi\,,\,(2k+1)\pi]$$

Before you write back with doubts, please do spend some time going back on the trigonometric circle, basic definitions and etc.

For your other questions post new threads **and add** in these your own effort, work, ideas, etc.